# If I move one electron does the rest of the Universe react to that change from QFT perspective?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

I apologize if this is something super trivial: I couldn't find any answers myself so decided to finally ask my first question on Physics.SE.

Classically speaking, if I move one electron from A to B (with the necessary acceleration) then the rest of the charges in the Universe would be affected since the classical EM wave would spread in all directions and would eventually wiggle all these charges (and they would  in turn wiggle some other charges and so on).

The classical perspective seems very clear but I am completely lost about what happens from the quantum field theory perspective. Assume I move the electron from A to B and a photon(s) is emitted. This photon will eventually, say, kick some electron in some atom to some excited state and this is it?

Would *the rest of the electrons* in the Universe be repelled differently now that the original electron is no longer where it was before? Would they move ever so slightly as a result?

As I understand it QFT suggests that electron repulsion has to do with the exchange of "virtual photons" but since the electron was moved from A to B shouldn't the rest of the electrons in the universe move ever so slightly in response to that movement?